# Unresolved reference jupiter and assertTrue when running Junit 5 Android tests

Tags: android, kotlin, junit5, android-instrumentation

I am trying to create an Android test class in Kotlin that deals with `Bitmap` but I can't manage to run the test because of these errors. They only occur for any test class in *androidTest* but the simple JVM tests in *test* run without problem.

First, this is how my test class looks like

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue

class RoundImageTest {

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    fun imagesRatio() {
        // test with square images
        val squareBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
             164, 164, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        assertTrue(squareBitmap.height == squareBitmap.width)
    }
}
```

Following the instructions specified [here](https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5) I have this in my project's *build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'eu.appcom.gradle:android-versioning:1.0.2'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
    classpath "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-gradle-plugin:1.10.0"
    classpath "org.jlleitschuh.gradle:ktlint-gradle:9.2.1"
    classpath("de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:1.6.2.0")
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

and this in my application's *build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'eu.appcom.gradle.android-versioning'

apply plugin: 'maven'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.demoapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode versioning.getVersionCode()
        versionName versioning.getVersionName()
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [
                        "room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas" . toString(),
                        "room.incremental": "true",
                        "room.expandProjection": "true"
                ]
            }
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArgument("runnerBuilder", "de.mannodermaus.junit5.AndroidJUnit5Builder")
    }
    testBuildType "alpha"
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas" . toString())
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['debugKeyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['debugKeyPassword']
            storeFile file(rootDir.getCanonicalPath() + '/' + keystoreProperties['debugKeyStore'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['debugStorePassword']
        }
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['releaseKeyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['releaseKeyPassword']
            storeFile file(rootDir.getCanonicalPath() + '/' + keystoreProperties['releaseKeyStore'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['releaseStorePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        alpha {
            applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
        exclude "META-INF/LICENSE*"
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // AndroidX
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.0'

    // ACRA
    implementation "ch.acra:acra-mail:$acra_version"
    implementation "ch.acra:acra-notification:$acra_version"

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$androidx_version"

    // ViewModel Kotlin support
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // Co-routines
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines"

    // Material UI
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"

    // LeakCanary
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.2'
    alphaImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.2'

    // Navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'

    // Junit
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.3.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation "de.mannodermaus.junit5:android-test-core:1.2.0"
    androidTestRuntimeOnly "de.mannodermaus.junit5:android-test-runner:1.2.0"

    // Espresso
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'
}
```

**Now**, when I try to run the test, this is what the *Build Output* shows me

> Task :app:compileAlphaAndroidTestKotlin FAILED
> e: RoundImageTest.kt:  (5, 18): Unresolved reference: jupiter
> e: RoundImageTest.kt: (9,  16): Unresolved reference: jupiter
> e: RoundImageTest.kt: (16, 9): Unresolved reference: assertTrue
> e: RoundImageTest.kt: (23, 9): Unresolved reference: assertTrue
> e: RoundImageTest.kt: (30, 9): Unresolved reference: assertTrue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, what I had to do was change

```
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2'
```

to

```
androidTestImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2'
```